# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, wildfly

I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: TblEmployee is not mapped [FROM TblEmployee]
    Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: TblEmployee` is not mapped
```

I researched the internet and it says I am not using the class name but the table name.  I made sure I am doing this correctly.  I am trying to connect to a sql server db.

JPA:

```
package com.ray.adtf.jpa;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
/**
 * The persistent class for the tblEmployee database table.
 */

@Entity
@Table(name="tblEmployee")
@NamedQuery(name="TblEmployee.findAll", query="SELECT t FROM TblEmployee t")
public class TblEmployee implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="EmployeeID")
    private int employeeID;
```

ejbpackage

```
com.ray.adtf.ejb;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import com.ray.adtf.jpa.TblEmployee;
import java.util.List;

@Stateless
public class GridMasterBean {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

        public List<TblEmployee> getDisplayGridList() {
            return em.createQuery("select t FROM TblEmployee t", TblEmployee.class).getResultList();

    }
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
 <persistence-unit name="Test-Persistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
 <jta-data-source>java:/ProgramHierarchy</jta-data-source>
 <class>com.ray.adtf.jpa.TblEmployee</class>
 <class>com.ray.adtf.jpa.TblProgram</class>
 <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
 </persistence-unit>
 </persistence>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not the issue you found, but when using Hibernate (or JPA or other ORM), I would advice stop using DB concepts (v.g., the `Tbl` in `TblEmployee`)

Comment: There is inconsistency in your persistence.xml as you are declaring both `transaction-type` transactions and `jta-data-source`. I am assuming you want to use JTA transactions so `transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"` is not required.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing HQL with JPA classes.

`EntityManager` is from JPA. JPA's Query will expect that you use JPQL (JPA Query Language), like the prepared query in the entity (`SELECT t FROM TblEmployee t`)

Now, `FROM TblEmployee` is HQL (Hibernate Query Language), you should use it when you are not using Hibernate as a JPA provider but directly (using Hibernate classes such as `Session`).

In short:

If you are including imports from `java.persistence`, do not add imports from `org.hibernate` and use JPQL (begins with `SELECT`).

If you are using Hibernate directly, do not use JPA classes like `EntityManager` and related. It seems that you can use either JPQL or HQL with the Hibernate queries, though.

Some thought food:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html

http://what-when-how.com/hibernate/querying-with-hql-and-jpa-ql-hibernate/

Comment: Thanks so I modified my ejb to return em.createQuery("select t FROM TblEmployee t", TblEmployee.class).getResultList();

Comment: I also took out all references to HQL but the same error.  The links are helpful but I was not able to solve my issue

Comment: Your code as a desktop application (no EJB, only JPA) runs just fine (I can provide a link if you want to check for differences). For WildFly, the `transaction-type` usually is JTA or you have to do additional configuration (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/ogm/4.1/reference/en-US/html/ogm-configuration.html#ogm-configuration-environments-javaee). But if it was the issue I would expect a different exception to be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared your entity classes in persistence.xml config file:

```
<property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>
```